# event handler for page modification

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint, event-handling, sharepoint-api

i want to handle events that are occuring on a aspx Page specifically sharepoint webpart page .

i ddnt find anything in visual studio event receivers .

is there any way to achieve this ?

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Is it SharePoint 2007 or 2010. If you're on 2010 then it's very easy to do using Visual Studio 2010: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453149.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What types of events ?
If you want to use the methods in the [page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=VS.90).aspx) , you can create a WebPart and override the methods : OnInit, OnLoad ...

[image]

source : http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/SharePoint-Web-Part-Event-Flow-in-detail.aspx